# Calculating difference between datetime stamp in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, strftime

I want to calculate the difference between two columns containing datetime stamps in db browser SQLite, I want the answers in minutes, and it keeps returning "Null". Please what could be the reason and how can I solve it?
I tried using this;

SELECT
started_at,
ended_at,
(strftime('%M','ended_at') - strftime('%M','started_at'))as duration
FROM citi1;

Answer (score 0):

You have `'started_at'` and `'ended_at'` which are string literals and not identifiers and SQLite returns `null` when you use them in `strftime()`.

But, even if you remove the single quotes you will not get the timestamp difference, because subtracting only the minutes parts of 2 timestamps does not return their difference.
For example, the difference that you would get for `started_at = '2022-03-31 13:15:00'` and `ended_at = '2022-03-31 14:00:00'` would be `-15` (= 0 - 15).

Use `strftime('%s', some_date)` which returns the number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00` for both timestamps, subtract and divide by 60 to get the correct difference in minutes:

```
SELECT started_at, ended_at, 
       (strftime('%s', ended_at) - strftime('%s', started_at)) / 60 AS duration 
FROM citi1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=de765e8f26d090b8833da1276126cc46).

Comment: It still returned Null and besides the datetime stamp does not contain seconds. This is an example - 16/03/2021 08:32

Comment: @OLUFUNKE the only valid text date format for SQLite is `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`. All SQLite datetime functions work with that format only and with any other format they return null. Check this: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html So change the format of your timestamps.

Comment: please I need help in changing the format

Comment: @OLUFUNKE check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b06cb78625d1333dda524e1d9fe4825b